# Add a background color in the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal:
When you are entering the address calculation or project.html, one of the main element in the menu should be marked with a background color based on the webpage you are entering. For instance, if you are entering calculation.html the selection named Calculation (from the menu) should be selected by having a different background color compare to others.

Problem:

> I don't know how to make a mark by having a background color once you
>   have clicked the link. I would like the code to be written in jQuery.

If possible, it would be great to add "id" in the element "a href" to change the background color.

The value "Project" and "calculation" from jQuery is the value of element title from the html code.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-menu">
    <ul id="kthh">
        <li><a href="calculation.html">Kalkylering</a></li>
        <li><a href="project.html">Projekt</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

var data = $('title'); 

    if(data[0].textContent == "Project")
    {
        $('#kthh').closest('li').next('li').find('a').addClass("asdd");

    }
    if(data[0].textContent == "calculation")
    {
        //$('title').html('someHTML'); 
    }

}); // ready
```

CSS:

```
/* Menu for display */

#nav-menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav-menu li
{
    float: right;
}

#nav-menu li a
{
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 110px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#nav-menu li a:hover {  background: #AA1133;}

#nav-menu li.last-child { padding-right: 50px;}

.asdd
{
    background: #AA1133;
}
```

Comment: Often this is done server side. What server side technology are you using? Any reason it has to be client side? In general you should try and design things so they work even if js isn't enabled.

Comment: I understand. In this context, i must use html, css and javascript only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use `textcontent`but `text`:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    var data = $('title'); 

    if(data[0].text () == "Project")
    {
        $('#myFirstButton').addClass("asdd");

    }
    if(data[0].text() == "calculation")
    {
        //...
    }

});
```

You can simplify your life by adding an Id to all your button also:

```
<div id="nav-menu">
    <ul id="kthh">
        <li><a id="myFirstButton" href="calculation.html">Kalkylering</a></li>
        <li><a id="mySecondButton" href="project.html">Projekt</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```